# Simple SQL Script in W3Schools not working

Tags: sql, lookup-tables

I am currently learning SQL and using the [W3Schools Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc) to play around. I am trying to update a table using a lookup from another table. I looked online and figured out the following code to run:

```
UPDATE OrderDetails
SET OrderDetails.ProductID = Orders.CustomerID
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails
ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
```

But it is coming up with the following error: "Error 1: could not prepare statement (1 near ".": syntax error)"

Is there a problem with my code or are there things that W3Schools doesn't want to run?

Comment: the update with join  syntax is specific for each db  .. so you should tell us which db you are really using

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ can also be used for basic SQL tests.

Comment: @ScaisEdge, neither your SQLServer script nor the MySQL script work in W3Schools. I guess it runs using neither syntax and I'd need to dig deeper to find out which it does support. Halley's code below does work. Does anyone know what that version would be called?

Answer (score 1):

The update with join syntax is specific for each db

The query you are using is valid for SQLSERVER

```
UPDATE OrderDetails
SET OrderDetails.ProductID = Orders.CustomerID
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN OrderDetails
ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
```

but not for my MySQL

```
UPDATE OrderDetails
INNER JOIN OrderDetails
ON OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
SET OrderDetails.ProductID = Orders.CustomerID
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
UPDATE OrderDetails
SET ProductID = (SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders WHERE OrderDetails.OrderID = Orders.OrderID)
WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID FROM Orders);
```

Is this what you want?